# YouTube api playlist - Get each video updated date

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Usually I can grab the updated date from each video using the channel feed

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<username>/uploads?max-results=50
```

then

```
video.Updated //gets video's last updated date
```

My question is how do I do the same thing when using a playlist feed?

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/<playlistGUID>?v=2&max-results=50
```

when I try and do `video.Update` for a video in the playlist, I get the default 12/31/1970.
I can't seem to find the correct call in the youtube api playlist reference, can anybody help me?